# How can I move global packages into a virtual environment after creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I use python virtual environments regularly and generally execute the standard method of installing any necessary site packages after running installing the virtual environment.  However, when I don't want to use all of the original environment's site-packages then in order to install a number of additional packages to the new environment I find the process tedious, especially when non pypi pacakges are required for my work.  I haven't managed to find a means of moving a global site package into an existing virtual environment. The work flow for this is as follows

I'd like to be able to first create a virtual environment from a full python installation, without using the `--system-site-packages`option.  Then, I'd like to be able to selectively move site-pacakges over to the new virtual environment.

This is, of course, something that I can get by without, but it would be a convenience if it is possible.

Comment: The usual thing to do is to install any  packages you need in the virtualenv again.  Activate the environment and use pip or easy_install.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I appreciate the help and I fully aware of the standard method.  I'll edit my post to clear that up.

Comment: What I guess @RobertMoskal wants to say and would be my opinion on it as well: That's not what the virtual environment system was designed for and how it should be used. Most likely if you are able to copy stuff over, you are going to break many of the features of pip, easy_install and the virtual environment.