# Can I copy sklearn from system packages into a virtual environment?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv on ubuntu, with among other things pandas working. I want to start using sklearn inside the venv, but pip install sklearn does not work. I was able to install sklearn using 
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
However, now it is installed in the system packages (and not inside the virtual environment).

Is there a way to get sklearn available inside the env? (I had the virtualenv activated when I installed sklearn, but that appears not to make a difference)

I looked at [How can I move global packages into a virtual environment after creating a virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885524/how-can-i-move-global-packages-into-a-virtual-environment-after-creating-a-virtu) , but this doesn't help: pip gives errors when trying to install sklearn

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, this is in principle possible. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages. 
However fixing the error is probably a better way for you to go.

Comment: Thank you, took your advice. Aparently I was missing a fortran compiler.